# Inconsistent Results With Base64 Decode PHP

Tags: php, json, base64, linden-scripting-language

I have a script in second life building a json string which is base64 encoded and sent to a PHP script.

```
Login(string action)
{
    string json_string = "{\"Action\": \""+action+"\", \"Name\": \""+simName+"\", \"OwnersKey\": \""+ (string)llGetOwner() +"\", \"ObjectID\": \""+ (string)objectID +"\", \"ParcelName\": \""+ parcelName +"\"}";
    string data = "Data=" + llStringToBase64(json_string);
    toWebPage(data);
}

toWebPage(string params)
{
    params += "&FromSL=true";
    string tst = "";
    if(DEBUG)
    {
        tst = "/tst";
    }
    myRequest = llHTTPRequest(URL + PRODUCTNAME + tst + "/"+controller+".php",
  [HTTP_METHOD, "POST",
   HTTP_MIMETYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"],
   params);
}
```

There are two times I call the Login script.

```
Login("RegisterTower");
```

creating the json string

```
{"Action": "RegisterTower", "Name": "Korzun", "OwnersKey": "8d13fa0f-b54d-43c9-8426-f7cb28f93cfd", "ObjectID": "be4885a4-a596-6a65-925e-470f149e9b63", "ParcelName": "~Lost Lands~"}
```

and

```
Login("CheckInTower");
```

creating the json string

```
{"Action": "CheckInTower", "Name": "Korzun", "OwnersKey": "8d13fa0f-b54d-43c9-8426-f7cb28f93cfd", "ObjectID": "be4885a4-a596-6a65-925e-470f149e9b63", "ParcelName": "~Lost Lands~"}
```

These json strings a base64 encoded and sent to the php script. The first script they hit is Main.php

```
<?php
include_once "Controller.php";
$params = $_GET;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $params = $_POST;
}
Controller::Process($params);
?>
```

Controller is as such

```
<?php
include_once 'Common.php';
include_once 'Entities.php';
include_once 'Database.php';

<?php
class Controller
{
    public static function Process($data)
    {
        echo base64_decode($data["Data"]);
    }
}
?>
```

When I check the results I get

```
{"Action": "RegisterTower", "Name": "Korzun", "OwnersKey": "8d13fa0f-b54d-43c9-8426-f7cb28f93cfd", "ObjectID": "be4885a4-a596-6a65-925e-470f149e9b63", "ParcelName": "~Lost Lands~"}
{"Action": "CheckInTower", "Name": "Korzun", "OwnersKey": "8d13fa0f-b54d-43c9-8426-f7cb28f93cfd", "ObjectID": "be4885a4-a596-6a65-925e-470f149e9b63", "ParcelName": "~Lost LandsHŸ
```

Why does the second json string decode with

```
"~Lost LandsHŸ
```

when the first did it

```
"~Lost Lands~"}
```

UPDATE: As suggested by Decent Dabble
The contents of $data["Data"] each time is

```
eyJBY3Rpb24iOiAiUmVnaXN0ZXJUb3dlciIsICJOYW1lIjogIktvcnp1biIsICJPd25lcnNLZXkiOiAiOGQxM2ZhMGYtYjU0ZC00M2M5LTg0MjYtZjdjYjI4ZjkzY2ZkIiwgIk9iamVjdElEIjogImJlNDg4NWE0LWE1OTYtNmE2NS05MjVlLTQ3MGYxNDllOWI2MyIsICJQYXJjZWxOYW1lIjogIn5Mb3N0IExhbmRzfiJ9
```

and

```
eyJBY3Rpb24iOiAiQ2hlY2tJblRvd2VyIiwgIk5hbWUiOiAiS29yenVuIiwgIk93bmVyc0tleSI6ICI4ZDEzZmEwZi1iNTRkLTQzYzktODQyNi1mN2NiMjhmOTNjZmQiLCAiT2JqZWN0SUQiOiAiYmU0ODg1YTQtYTU5Ni02YTY1LTkyNWUtNDcwZjE0OWU5YjYzIiwgIlBhcmNlbE5hbWUiOiAifkxvc3QgTGFuZHN In0=
```

I am assuming now i have posted this, the problem is the space at the end of the second one. The original data I send is

```
eyJBY3Rpb24iOiAiQ2hlY2tJblRvd2VyIiwgIk5hbWUiOiAiS29yenVuIiwgIk93bmVyc0tleSI6ICI4ZDEzZmEwZi1iNTRkLTQzYzktODQyNi1mN2NiMjhmOTNjZmQiLCAiT2JqZWN0SUQiOiAiYmU0ODg1YTQtYTU5Ni02YTY1LTkyNWUtNDcwZjE0OWU5YjYzIiwgIlBhcmNlbE5hbWUiOiAifkxvc3QgTGFuZHN+In0=
```

So now how do I solve that???

Comment: Can you show use the contents of `$data["Data"]` from both times *before* you `base64_decode()` them?

Comment: Updated with results

Comment: Yep, you're assumptions are very likely to be correct, as I was just looking into the `base64_decode()` documentation for an earlier question, where [this comment on PHP's documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#102113) offered a (likely) fix: replace spaces with `+` signs. That's why I asked for the base64 encoded data. :)

Comment: `str_replace(' ','+',$str)`?

Comment: Thanks Decent Dabbler, can you add your comment as an answer so I can tick it :D

Comment: @TomHanson if the question is solved and Dabbler doesn't post his solution as an answer, you could add an answer yourself (and later accept it).